# retrieve the Many side of association in Doctrine2

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two entities one is Role and other is User , I want to build forms and reports to add and show each role with their users , and to create a user with one Role so its User:Role (One-To-Many), I managed to add role to a user via Doctrine 2 but I cannot show users fro each role below is my code

```
<?php

/**
* Description of Role
* @Entity
* @Table=(name"Roles")
* @author alaaqashou
*/
class Role {
//put your code here

/**
 *
 * @var integer $id
 * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Column(length=100,nullable=false,unique=true)
 * @var type 
 */

private $name;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User" ,mappedBy="Role")
 * @var type 
 */

private $users;

public function __construct() {
   $this->users=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function getUsers() {
    return $this->users;
}

public function setUsers($user) {
    $this->users->add($user);
}

}

/**
* Description of User
*@Entity
* @Tabel(name="Users")
* @author alaaqashou
*/
class User {
//put your code here

/**
 *
 * @var integer $id
 * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @Column(length=255,nullable=false,unique=true)
 * 
 * 
 * @var type 
 * 
 */

private $role;

function __construct() {
    $this->created=new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
}

public function getRole() {
    return $this->role;
}

public function setRole($role) {
    $this->role = $role;
}

}
```

I got the Notice: Undefined index: Role error when I try to do the following

my Service

```
     public function listAllRole()
      {
     return $this->em->getRepository('sihha\Entity\Role')->findAll();

     }
$roles=$this->roleService->listAllRole();

$users=$roles[0]->getUsers();
// I even tried  $users=$roles[0]->getUsers()->toArray();

$user=$users[0];
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: I can not Access elements of DoctrineArrayCollection but the strange thing is you can do
$role->getUsers()->add($user);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the annotations. Try replacing `mappedBy='Role'` width `mappedBy='role'` (i.e. type "role" in lowercase).

I just tried `mappedBy="Table"` in one of my entities and it gave me the same result you seem to be having.

Comment: thank you very much , when I saw your answer I was yeah right , but I double checked it and now its working , Thanks man , but can you explain why, Iam afraid that Iam going to face such strange  errors , everything should be for a reason!!

Comment: I double checked the Doctrine docs and you were right, Iam suffering because I cannot get my code syntax to be validated, I wish for doctrine to be integrated in future zend release.

Comment: Quoting from the Doctrine docs: "The mappedBy attribute designates the field in the entity that is the owner of the relationship." (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html)

So basically I guess by default the fieldname for any property is lowercased. You can change it by using an annotation '@ORM\Column(name="[field_name]")'. If you were for example to set the name attribute to 'Field_name', you'd have to use mappedBy='Field_name'.